# Codeigniter MVC / Display all records in table

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code I wrote is only displaying the last row in the table. However I need to `loop` and display each `row` in the table.

## MODEL

```
class Catalog_products extends CI_Model {

    function Show_all_products()
    {

        $q = $this->db->get('printer');
       
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
            {
                $data = array();
                $data['id'] = $row->id;
                $data['name'] = $row->name; 
            }   

        return $data;

    }
    
}
```

## VIEW

```
<?php echo $id ?>
<?php echo $name ?>
```

## CONTROLLER

```
public function catalog()
{

    $this->load->model('Catalog_products');
    $data = $this->Catalog_products->Show_all_products();
    $this->load->view('catalog', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model:

```
function Show_all_products()
{
   return $this->db->get('printer')->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
$data['products'] = $this->Catalog_products->Show_all_products();
$this->load->view('catalog', $data);
```

View:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->id;
    echo $product->name;
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you- Can you please give a short explanation if you don't mind. Thank you.

Comment: What part would you like me to clarify?

Comment: Why `$result` and not `$return`? And i was under the impression that all DB logic should be in the `MODEL` However you moved some of it to the `VIEW`to make the `foreach` loop. Is it mandatory for the `foreach` loop to be in the view for this work properly or this just for convenience ?

Comment: `$this->db->get('table_name')->result()` returns an object which holds the entire result set. If you want an array you can use `result_array()`. It is a matter of convenience. The view doesn't hold any logic. It only outputs the products. This is simply a loop in order to display all the products. If you want to do some manipulation on the data returned from the DB, do it in the model and then return it to the controller. The view is used just for the output.

Comment: Ah i See. Thanks for the detail. The only manipulation I made was to echo to a list. In the `VIEW` i did:  `<?php foreach($products as $product) :?>

<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/products/<?php echo $product->id; ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?> </a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>`  I made this to just generate all my links. Do you think I did this well? Or is there a better way?

Comment: That's the correct way to work in a view. For cleaner links you can use the `site_url` function: `<a href="<?php echo site_url('main/products/'.$product->id); ?>">`

Comment: Thanks Yan!  What's the benefit of `site_url` over `base_url` wouldn't they both show the entire url `http://...` ---- Just tried `site_url` -> returns a 404 page not found error.. Do I need to config that somewhere?

Comment: The benefit is code readability. In my opinion, the `site_url` option is easier to read.

Comment: Here's a good a questions for you---> In the DB record there are 100 ids/names --> How do I insert a <ul> </ul> every 20 records so that I can style this out over 5 COL's in my CSS. Do I need to `count` the foreach ?

Comment: This is out of the scope of this question. Please ask a new one.

Comment: You're Model function sample 'Show_all_products' is missing $this->load->database()